# Issues with intel intrinsics

Tags: c, intel, intrinsics

Hi everyone I'm trying to use the intel intrinsics like so

```
void test()
{
    uint16_t n1 = 5;
    uint16_t n2 = 2;
    __m64 vec1, vec2, res;

    vec1 = _mm_set_pi16(n1, n1, n1, n1);
    vec2 = _mm_set_pi16(n2, n2, n2, n2);

    res = _mm_add_pi16(vec1, vec2);

    printf("%u %u %u %u \n", vec1[0], vec1[1], vec1[2], vec1[3]);
    printf("%u %u %u %u \n", vec2[0], vec2[1], vec2[2], vec2[3]);
    printf("%u %u %u %u \n", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3]);
}
```

but the weird thing that I'm getting this results :

```
327685 327685 131074 131074 
131074 131074 458759 458759 
458759 458759 327685 327685
```

I'm using eclipse Mars... and I'm including the **mmintrin.h**,  **xmmintrin.h**,  **emmintrin.h**.

Please can someone explain what's wrong with this

Comment: You should probably be using `__m128i` SSE vectors in new code, not 64 bit MMX.  SSE2 support is pretty safe to assume as a baseline even in 32-bit code, and is guaranteed for x86-64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencing `__m64` as array is non-standard.
I don't know how your compiler handles it.
I am using Intel Compiler in Visual Studio, and get a compilation error.
You should extract `uint16` elements from MMX register to ALU register before printing.
Use `_mm_extract_pi16` intrinsic to extract the value.

Don't forget to call `_mm_empty()` intrinsic function before exit the function.

See the following code sample:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

static void Test()
{
    uint16_t n1=5;
    uint16_t n2=2;
    __m64 vec1,vec2,res;

    vec1 = _mm_set_pi16 (n1 ,n1 ,n1 ,n1);
    vec2 = _mm_set_pi16 (n2 ,n2 ,n2 ,n2);

    res = _mm_add_pi16 (vec1, vec2);

    //uint16_t res0 = _mm_extract_pi16(res, 0);
    //uint16_t res1 = _mm_extract_pi16(res, 1);
    //uint16_t res2 = _mm_extract_pi16(res, 2);
    //uint16_t res3 = _mm_extract_pi16(res, 3);

    printf("%u %u %u %u \n",_mm_extract_pi16(vec1, 0),_mm_extract_pi16(vec1, 1),_mm_extract_pi16(vec1, 2),_mm_extract_pi16(vec1, 3));
    printf("%u %u %u %u \n",_mm_extract_pi16(vec2, 0),_mm_extract_pi16(vec2, 1),_mm_extract_pi16(vec2, 2),_mm_extract_pi16(vec2, 3));
    printf("%u %u %u %u \n",_mm_extract_pi16(res, 0),_mm_extract_pi16(res, 1),_mm_extract_pi16(res, 2),_mm_extract_pi16(res, 3));

    _mm_empty();
}

int main()
{
    Test();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 5 5 5
2 2 2 2
7 7 7 7
```

Comment: IIRC, the ABI requires the FPU to be in x87 state on function calls.  So you should `_mm_empty()` before calling printf.  The OP wouldn't have this problem if they use SSE instead of obsolete MMX.

Comment: MMX belong to the 90's, you must use SSE... Even if it's just for academic purpose... please use SSE !!!

Answer (score 3):

Let's convert those values to hexadecimal strings:

```
0x00050005    0x00050005    0x00020002    0x00020002
0x00020002    0x00020002    0x00070007    0x00070007
0x00070007    0x00070007    0x00050005    0x00050005
```

It appears that the compiler is not applying the usual integral promotions to a subscripted `__m64` variable, so that each value you pass is consuming 16 bits of parameter space (probably on the stack), and then `printf` is decoding 32 bits for each `%u`.

You should be able to fix this with explicit casts, like:

```
printf("%u %u %u %u \n", (unsigned int)vec1[0], (unsigned int)vec1[1],
                         (unsigned int)vec1[2], (unsigned int)vec1[3]);
```

Integral promotions are supposed to be applied to parameters of variadic functions... but if the result of subscripting here is not exactly one of the integral types, then that rule no longer applies.

Comment: So, how can i fix it? any idea ? The problem is the same with **_mm_set_pi8** and **_mm_add_pi16** but it's working for 32

Comment: @A.nechi: The problem is only in passing values to `printf()` for display... the calculations are being done right.  You can fix the display by casting to the exact type `printf()` wants.